# How to Save/Load Image/Videos from Camera Roll

Tags: image, swift

In Obj-C:

```
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
```

How would I do the same in Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enums work differently in Swift compared to Objective-C. The type is UIImagePickerControllerSourceType, but the values are accessed with dot notation:

```
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
```

Since the attribute you are setting is already known to be of type UIImagePickerControllerSourceType, you can skip that part and just write:

```
picker.sourceType = .Camera
```